# org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException

Tags: java, spring

`applicationContext-service.xml`

```
<bean id="taskAllOverService" scope="singleton" class="TaskAllOverService"/>
<bean id="taskAllOverStateCodeService" scope="singleton" class="TaskAllOverStateCodeService"/>


public class TaskAllOverService {
    protected Integer taskId;
    public Integer getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(Integer taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

}

public class TaskAlloverStateCodeService extend TaskAllOverService {
    public List find() {
     .......
    }

}
```

INITIALIZING SPRING ROOT WEBAPPLICATIONTEXT too long time,and report error :
[ERROR] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
what should i do ? appreciate for your help!

Comment: Can you post your configuration ?, Also post the list of jars you have included, if using maven the pom.xml should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you don't include spring-beans schema on your spring context xml file.
Probably you only include spring-context schema

I'm not sure what else you need, but if you need spring-beans and spring-context on spring version 3.x then spring context will be like below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency to the pom.xml worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```